# How to get the default system palette?

Tags: c++, qt

By default Qt sets blue highlight. This is how my widget looks:

[image: how my widget looks]

And this is how I want to make it look like (the purple highlight):

[image: how I want to make it look like]

Can I get the default system palette? (my desktop environment is Cinnamon)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you applied any style to your application? Can you please edit your question to include a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a small, working code where we can see how do you initialize your application).